# UTF-8 encoding problem with XSLT via PHP

Tags: php, xslt, encoding, utf-8

I'm facing a nasty encoding issue when transforming XML via XSLT through PHP.

The problem can be summarised/dumbed down as follows: when I copy a (UTF-8 encoded) XHTML file with an XSLT stylesheet, some characters are displayed wrong. When I just show the same XHTML file, all characters come out correctly.

Following files illustrate the problem:

## XHTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>encoding test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is how we d&#239;&#223;&#960;&#955;&#509; &#145;special characters&#146;</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

## XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## PHP

```
<?php
  $xml_file = 'encoding_test.xml';
  $xsl_file = 'encoding_test.xsl';

  $xml_doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $xml_doc->load($xml_file);

  $xsl_doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $xsl_doc->load($xsl_file);

  $xp = new XsltProcessor();
  $xp->importStylesheet($xsl_doc);

  // alllow to bypass XSLT transformation with bypass=true request parameter
  if ($bypass = $_GET['bypass']) {
    echo file_get_contents($xml_file);
  }
  else {
    echo $xp->transformToXML($xml_doc);
  }
?>
```

When this script is invoked as such (via e.g. http://localhost/encoding_test/encoding_test.php), all characters in the transformed XHTML document come out ok, except for the &#145; and &#146; character entities (they're opening and closing single quotation marks). I'm not a Unicode expert, but two things strike me:

1. all other character entities are interpreted correctly (which could imply something about the UTF-8-ness of `&#145;` and `&#146;`)
2. yet, when the XHTML file is displayed unmediated (via e.g. http://localhost/encoding_test/encoding_test.php?bypass=true), *all* characters are displayed properly.

I think I've declared UTF-8 encoding for the output anywhere I could. Do others perhaps see what's wrong and can be righted?

Thanks in advance!

Ron Van den Branden

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`&#145;` and `&#146;` are no visible Unicode characters.

They are old HTML character references<sup>1</sup> for single quotes, but when you process them using an XSLT processor the processor doesn't see single quotes but the Unicode characters with decimal codes 145 and 146, i.e. [U+0090 and U+0091](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

These characters are private use (i.e. the usage is not defined by the Unicode consortium) [C1 control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes).

The solution is to use the correct Unicode characters `&#x2018;` and `&#x2019;`.

<sup>1</sup><sub>In fact, these are codes that map to [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding. They are displayed by browsers but they are actually [not valid in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/draft-ietf-html-i18n-05.txt):</sub>

> NOTE -- the above SGML declaration, like that of HTML 2.0,
>           specifies the character numbers 128 to 159 (80 to 9F hex)
>           as UNUSED.  This means that numeric character references
>           within that range (e.g.  ’) are illegal in HTML.  Neither ISO 8859-1 nor ISO 10646 contain characters in that
>           range, which is reserved for control characters.

Comment: +1 very good explanation! Also for other glyphs reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

Comment: The HTML 5 draft goes further: "The numeric character reference forms described above are allowed to reference any Unicode code point other than U+0000, U+000D, permanently undefined Unicode characters (noncharacters), and control characters other than space characters."

Comment: Phew, thanks a lot! Very kind of you to provide a helpful solution besides a clear explanation.